# Staging table query return as table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table (ReportTest) in which I have the other table(Defectpareto) columns. I am trying to access the Defectpareto table columns using ReportTest table. But I am not able to do it. 
I tried to write a stored procedure and query, both are returning me the string as output

```
ReportTest table:
ID_column Reportname    Tablename       Column1     Column2     Column3
1         Defect_Pareto Defectpareto    ID_Column   Defectname  Defectcount

Defectpareto table:
ID_column   Defectname  Defectcount
1           Breakdown   15
2           Temperature 300
```

query:

```
`SeLECT COALESCE (CHAR(13), '') + 'Select Column2, Column3 FROM '+ Tablename + ' Where ID_Column = 1' FROM ReportTest`
```

stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER  PROCEDURE [dbo].[StgTable]
AS

BEGIN
DECLARE @Tables VARCHAR(8000) 
SeLECT @Tables = COALESCE(@Tables + CHAR(13), '') + 'SELECT Column2, Column3 FROM '+ Tablename + ' Where ID_Column = 1'
FROM ReportTest
select @Tables
end
```

How can I proceed with this to get the table as output

Comment: I would store the required data in the #temp table and will return it!

Comment: I have a table (ReportTest) in which I have the other table(Defectpareto) columns. - why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have your columns and table name on a string you just need to dynamically call that SQL string using **exec**.

Change :

```
declare @DynSQL varchar(1000) 
set @DynSQL = 'select ......'

select @DynSQL
```

with :

```
declare @DynSQL varchar(1000);

select @DynSQL = ' SELECT ' + Column2' + ', ' + Column3 + 
                 ' FROM '+ Tablename
from ReportTest
where ID_Column = 1;

exec (@DynTable);
```

Your tags are both for mySql and SQL Server. The answer I gave you is for SQL Server, which is what your code looks like to me.

Comment: Colum2 and Column3 shouldn't be part of your string, but be replaced with those column values. Something like : SeLECT @Tables = 'SELECT ' + Column2' + ', ' + Column3 + ' FROM '+ Tablename + ' Where ID_Column = 1'
FROM ReportTest

Comment: Thank you so much @Marc Guillot.  your solution helped me achieve it.

Comment: Hi, The where command points out the Defectpareto table, inorder to point the ReportTest table, I tried to remove the quotation **SeLECT @Tables = 'SELECT ' + Column2 + ', ' + Column3 + ' , ' + Column1 + ' FROM '+ Tablename +FROM ReportTest  where ID_Column = 2** but it doesn't work. Please let me know what am I missing

Comment: When you say that it doesn't work can you explain what it returns versus what do you intend to get ?.

Comment: I intend to use the where clause to ReportTest table so when I use the query I mentioned above it returns invalid syntax near FROM. To mention, I have added another row in my Reporttest table with another row of table named Alarms.

Comment: Ok, I have updated the answer to apply that where clausule to the ReportTest table. Is this now what you were looking for ?.

Comment: I tried it and is working fine. Thank you so much Marc Guillot.